# datetime picker don't show input of date

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I use datetime picker in this way:

```
<datetimepicker 
    hour-step="vm.hourStep" 
    minute-step="vm.minuteStep" 
    ng-model="vm.time" 
    show-meridian="vm.showMeridian" 
    show-date="false"
    show-spinners="true"
    readonly-time="false"></datetimepicker>
```

and it shows the input like this way:

[image: My datetimepicker]

Is it possible to don't show the first input (date) with directive attribute (or css if no attribute is available) - I only need the time adjustment.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does vm.time = null in the directive controller help?

Comment: no, I need vm.time to get the time - I only will hide the first input! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Timepicker (ui.bootstrap.timepicker) available from [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Use it like this:

```
<uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></uib-timepicker>
```